# Finding first parent's last common ancestor with another branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to find out the number of commits that was made in my feature branch AFTER it diverged from my develop branch.

So in this instance, develop had **2** commits before feature-a diverged, and feature-a has **3** commits. This gives node E a code **2-3**.

```
develop   A - B --- F
               \
feature-a       C - D - E
```

Currently I'm using *'git rev-list --count'*, develop..HEAD to count the number of commits that exist both in develop and in feature-a (**2**: A & B), and using *'git rev-list --count HEAD'* to get the total number of commits in feature-a (5: ABCDE), and I'll take 5-2=**3**.

This works well until I merge feature-a into develop, such as so:

```
develop   A - B --- F --- CDE
               \         /
feature-a       C - D - E
```

Now when I try to find the last common ancestor of **E** & develop, it tells me that the last ancestor is **E**. Which makes sense when I think about it.

But I was trying to find my last common ancestor before the merge, or the last common ancestor of (E & CDG's *first parent*), which was **B**.

Does anyone know what command I can run in order to find **B**?

Comment: For this case only, `git merge-base CDE^ CDE^2` finds `B`. But I'm afraid the real situation may be more complicated.

Comment: "Currently I'm using 'git rev-list --count', develop..HEAD to count the number of commits that exist both in develop and in feature-a (2: A & B)" No. The `develop..HEAD` range (assuming `feature-a` is checked out) does **not** count that. It counts commits reachable from `feature-a` (so 5 : `A,B,C,D,E`) but NOT from `develop` (so we substract 2 (`A,B`)) which gives 3 (`C,D,E`).

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes I understand. I'm saying that I used that command to count that, which is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: @ElpieKay Unfortunately, yes. I do not know where CDE is or if it even exists. I only know that I'm at E.